# SQL Server : setting foreign key to a specific value

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm not sure what is the best way to structure my question.

I have a table with foreign key column in it. By default the foreign key is set to `NOT NULL` and I want to keep it that way for now, because maybe this will be the final result. But for now there could be records that don't need (and have) foreign keys values and I want to distinct them somehow so it is as clear as possible that these records are something different from the other.

I tried but as it seems I can not use negative numbers for `bigint` which is the value of the foreign key in my SQL Server table. I guess this is pretty standard stuff so what is the best thing to do in this situation besides making the foreign key to `NULL`?

Comment: Allow `NULL`s or add a row to the related table saying "TBD" and use its key.

Comment: I don't want to redesign because I'm pretty sure that at the end the foreign key will be required. I can set some default value like `6000` which won't be reached during programming, but it seems to me kinda.. dunno, I suspect there are better approaches to this.

Comment: So you have two constraints on the column (`NOT NULL` and foreign key) and you're asking how you can insert a value that doesn't meet those constraints?

Comment: A foreign key value needs to match a value in a related table, so you can't just pick `42` as meaning "I'll figure it out later."  You could replace the foreign key relation with a constraint that allows either a valid value from another table or a magic number, e.g. `35071`.

Comment: You can also implement your choice of flexible validation rules in triggers.  They're quite useful, but many people avoid them because they can get tricky, because they aren't used to looking for them, ... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why HABO didn't make that the answer, because that's pretty much your only option.

1. Make it NULL
2. Create a row in the referenced table and set it to TBD or whatever moniker you prefer and use the ID from that instead of NULL

If you have records that do not need an FK and never will, then you should set the column to NULL, else use a temp value.

You cannot use a negative value because you MUST reference something in the foreign table if you have a foreign key constraint.

Comment: To draw out the grammatical metaphor Mike alludes to: Foreign Key NULL -> "MIGHT have". Foreign Key NOT NULL -> "MUST have."

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key *constraints* enforces you to refer an existing PK of the other table.

One way not mentioned yet is to drop the constraint for now :

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  DROP CONSTRAINT fk_something
```